# Connecting Apache Drill to Amazon S3 using DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-drill

I'm trying to connect apache drill to my aws s3 without specifying my access key and secret key in the config, so I add

```
"fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider": "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain"
```

in the config hoping it will get the credentials from the default credential profiles file in my PC and get the IAM Role when I deploy it.

When I specify the access key and secret key in the config, the connection work just fine, but after I change to config to use `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` it didn't work

the drill show this when i try to use s3 storage

```
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: AmazonClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
```

I can write to s3 using the `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` with `org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetWriter` and can read the s3 bucket using awscli without any problem

here is my storage plugin config

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "connection": "s3a://my-bucket",
  "config": {
    "fs.s3a.endpoint": "s3.REGION.amazonaws.com",
    "fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider": "com.amazonaws.auth.DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain"
  },
  "workspaces": {
    "tmp": {
      "location": "/tmp",
      "writable": true,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    },
    "root": {
      "location": "/",
      "writable": false,
      "defaultInputFormat": null,
      "allowAccessOutsideWorkspace": false
    }
  },
  "formats": {
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet"
    }
  },
  "enabled": true
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache Drill does not support `~/.aws/credentials`, but supports [Hadoop CredentialProvider API](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CredentialProviderAPI.html). To be able to use it, you need to create [an external credentials provider](https://drill.apache.org/docs/s3-storage-plugin/#using-an-external-provider-for-credentials) and set `"hadoop.security.credential.provider.path"` property (pointing to the provider) in `"config"` section of Drill's S3 Storage Plugin.

Alternatively, you may store your credentials in Drill's [core-site.xml](https://drill.apache.org/docs/s3-storage-plugin/#defining-access-keys-in-the-drill-core-site-xml-file).